# Why are interfaces used in Java when each method must be typed out again in the actual implementation?

Tags: java, interface

Why are interfaces used in Java when each method must be typed out again in the actual implementation? What's an example of a situation where writing out an interface makes things easier?

Comment: Read about [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) and why they serve as contracts and help your code be more flexible

Comment: One alternative as per C++ is to allow multiple inheritance which would allow you to inherit from two abstract classes but then has other issues which is one of the reasons the Java designers decided not to do that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interfaces define a contract, not an implementation. This allows you to divorce yourself from the actual implementation of an interface- as long as the implementation satisfies the contract, you're happy.

Say you call a method that returns a List (which is an interface). You can use that List because you know it has List functions like get() and add(). You don't have to worry about what *kind* of list it is. If the List happens to be an ArrayList and then the method changes to return a LinkedList instead, you don't have to change your code at all, since both are guaranteed to have the List functions.

Comment: So in other words, interfaces are useful when code requires multiple implementations of a similar blueprint and having such a blueprint/contract ensures that each individual implementation has all the necessary methods while allowing for case by case variation in implementation details?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to put it.

Comment: Oh wait. I see now you're talking more along the lines of defining interfaces to use as data types! (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) I was just thinking of when a class implements an interface.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest benefits of interfaces is that you can use the interface in the method arguments and return type. For example, you can write:

```
public List join (List list1, List list2)
{
    // some complicated stuff using list1.size() and list2.get() etc
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use Collection's, more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces have many advantages.

Assuming the following code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<String> getNames () {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String> ();

        // Populate list of names

        return names;
    }
}
```

As Kevin Workman mentioned in his excellent answer, an interface is used to define the contract that implenting classes will have to fulfill. In the above case, the `getNames` method states that it will return an instance of the interface `List`. However, the contract does not force you to use a specific `List` implementation; any concrete class that implements `List` can be used. In this case, an `ArrayList` was chosen.

Later on in your project, if you end up realizing that a `LinkedList` would be a better implementation for your application, you can easily change `List<String> names = new ArrayList<String> ();` to `List<String> names = new LinkedList<String> ();`, without having to change the method signature, or the rest of the existing code inside the method. This is a good practice, and it can prevent many problems and/or time loss in your projects.

Additionally, using interfaces allows you (or clients of your code) to define the concrete implementation that best suit their needs. In the case of `Map` implementations, some are faster, some are more space efficient.

Another advantage of interfaces can be appreciated when building a unit tests set. Most of the mocking framework, if not all of them, work with interfaces. It allows you to build tests that do not require to have every concrete test implementation hand coded, and allows the test code base to be much smaller/simpler.

When building an API that will be used by other developers, the use of interfaces can make your API much simpler, and facilitate your clients' experience with your API. An example of this would be the [DOM XML implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-frame.html) provided in Java. If you look at the API, there's pretty much only interfaces, no concrete classes are exposed. During the maintenance of this API, the developers can add/change/delete any concrete implementation without the fear of breaking backward compatibility with existing client code.

If they had made the concrete implementations public, they would have had their hands tied throughout the API's lifetime. For instance, assume they provided a faulty [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) public implementation named `BuggedElement`, and clients directly used it in their code. From this point on, they would be forced to maintain this implementation, rather than just removing it and writing a new implementation, otherwise existing projects using this concrete implementation would be forced to re-write pieces of code referring to `BuggedElement`.

But, since they opted to only provide interfaces in their public API, they have the luxury of either modifying existing implementations, or getting rid of them and writing new ones, and they will never break clients' code.